# How to algebraically add two vectors when they are not at the origin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Suppose we have three vectors, U, V, and W.  Vector U starts at (3,8) and ends at ()3,10).  Vector V starts at (6,5) and ends at (7,4). Vector W starts at (9,8) and ends at (12,2). How would one go about algebraically computing something like 2V-3U+5W?  I am aware of the parallelogram and the triangle methods, but I want to do it from an equation standpoint without using any graphics.  Problem is, the only way I know to add vectors only works when they are defined by a single point rather than start and finish.

Comment: Rewrite the vectors so that they are at the origin. So shift $V$ to the start $(0,0)$, then its end is $(1,-1)$. Then write $V=(1,-1)$. In this form you can add them just by adding the coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide an example? The answer for the problem is not a vector at the origin, and I am confused as to what to do after performing the indicated operations because I do not have a vector going from a nonzero coordinate to an endpoint like U, V, and W.

Comment: A _vector_ has no concept of starting at a particular point. The vector that goes from the point $(6,5)$ to the point $(7,4)$ _is the same vector as_ the one that goes from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(1,-1)$. Usually this vector is simply written $(1,-1)$.

Comment: "the only way I know to add vectors only works when they are defined by a single point rather than start and finish" -- That's because that **is** the only way to add vectors. If you get start and finish the first step is to convert to single-point. Who is telling you anything different? Exactly what makes you think so? It may help if you could quote the exact words and figures by which you think this person told you what you had to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If V starts at (6,5) and ends at (7,4) you can compute it (shift it to the origin) by

$$ V = (7,4) - (6,5) = (1, -1)$$

And the same for U and W. Then you can add U + V + W (or whatever linear combination you have) just as you already know.

Comment: The problem is that I end up with a singular point for my answer but the question expects a vector like the ones given, starting from a nonzero point

Comment: I don't understand your distinction. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The vector that starts at point $a$ and ends at point $b$ is simply equal to $b-a$, where the subtraction is done componentwise on the coordinates of $a$ and $b$.

Do this for each of the pairs of points you have, and then add the resulting vectors componentwise.  What you get will be the vector you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just note that for U, the x coordinate changed by 0 and the y coordinate changed by 2. So it's (0,2). Do something similar for the other vectors and then compute as normal.